# How to save image from drawing panel in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a `drawing panel` with some `color buttons`. I can draw with different `colors` in the `drawing panel`. There is also a `save button`. I want to capture the `image` drawn on the `panel` and `save` the captured `image` inside a directory in my pc, when I will click the `save button`. I don't know much about java. How can I do this?

**This is my code:**

```
package paint;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class paint{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Icon iconB = new ImageIcon("blue.gif");

    Icon iconM = new ImageIcon("magenta.gif");

    Icon iconR = new ImageIcon("red.gif");

    Icon iconBl = new ImageIcon("black.gif");

    Icon iconG = new ImageIcon("green.gif");


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint It");
    //Creates a frame with a title of "Paint it"

    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    //Creates a new container
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //sets the layout

    final PadDraw drawPad = new PadDraw();
    //creates a new padDraw, which is pretty much the paint program

    content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //sets the padDraw in the center

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    //creates a JPanel
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
    panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
    panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
    //This sets the size of the panel

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    //creates the clear button and sets the text as "Clear"
    clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.clear();
        }
    });
    //this is the clear button, which clears the screen.  This pretty
    //much attaches an action listener to the button and when the
    //button is pressed it calls the clear() method

            JButton saveButton = new JButton("save");

    JButton redButton = new JButton(iconR);
    //creates the red button and sets the icon we created for red
    redButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.red();
        }

    });
    //when pressed it will call the red() method.  So on and so on =]

    JButton blackButton = new JButton(iconBl);
    //same thing except this is the black button
    blackButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.black();
        }
    });

    JButton magentaButton = new JButton(iconM);
    //magenta button
    magentaButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.magenta();
        }
    });

    JButton blueButton = new JButton(iconB);
    //blue button
    blueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.blue();
        }
    });

    JButton greenButton = new JButton(iconG);
    //green button
    greenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.green();
        }
    });

    blackButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
    magentaButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
    redButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
    blueButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
    greenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16,16));
    //sets the sizes of the buttons

    panel.add(greenButton);
    panel.add(blueButton);
    panel.add(magentaButton);
    panel.add(blackButton);
    panel.add(redButton);
    panel.add(clearButton);
            panel.add(saveButton);
    //adds the buttons to the panel

    content.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //sets the panel to the left

    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    //sets the size of the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //makes it so you can close
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //makes it so you can see it
}
}


class PadDraw extends JComponent{
Image image;
//this is gonna be your image that you draw on
Graphics2D graphics2D;
//this is what we'll be using to draw on
int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
//these are gonna hold our mouse coordinates

//Now for the constructors
public PadDraw(){
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            oldX = e.getX();
            oldY = e.getY();
        }
    });
    //if the mouse is pressed it sets the oldX & oldY
    //coordinates as the mouses x & y coordinates
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();
            if(graphics2D != null)
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
        }

    });
    //while the mouse is dragged it sets currentX & currentY as the mouses x and y
    //then it draws a line at the coordinates
    //it repaints it and sets oldX and oldY as currentX and currentY
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if(image == null){
        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        clear();

    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
//this is the painting bit
//if it has nothing on it then
//it creates an image the size of the window
//sets the value of Graphics as the image
//sets the rendering
//runs the clear() method
//then it draws the image


public void clear(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}
//this is the clear
//it sets the colors as white
//then it fills the window with white
//thin it sets the color back to black
public void red(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.red);
    repaint();
}
//this is the red paint
public void black(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}
//black paint
public void magenta(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.magenta);
    repaint();
}
//magenta paint
public void blue(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
    repaint();
}
//blue paint
public void green(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.green);
    repaint();
}
//green paint
```

}

Comment: This is kind of a strange way(and probably not the best) to do it, but you could use [`Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to take a screenshot of the window.

Comment: Draw the line on an image, save the image using `ImageIO`..

Comment: You forgot a semi-colon after `Icon iconB = new ImageIcon("blue.gif")`.

Comment: @GoJava *"probably not the best"* Not probably, definitely. The `Robot` will fail if the app. is partially covered, or if part of the drawing is out of view in a scroll pane, or..

Comment: @GoJava How to use ROBOT?

Comment: I gave you a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to it in my first comment. It allows you to move the mouse and press keys. This could allow you to use the keyboard shortcut(Shift + Command + 4 for Mac) and press the cursor to capture a selection.

Comment: [Writing/Saving an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written save() method copy it to PadDraw class and call save() when ever you need to save the image.

```
public void save(){
    try {
        BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // Draw the image on to the buffered image
        Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
        bGr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(bimage , "PNG", new File("test.png"));
        bGr.dispose();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PadDraw.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush. It's working. But seems like whenever I save an image it replaces the first one because of the same name 'test.png'. Is there any solution?

Comment: You have to replace "test.png" to path of your image :)

Answer (score 1):

The basics for creating an image of any Swing component is use:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
component.print( g2d );
g2d.dispose();
```

Then you can save the "image" using `ImageIO`.

Or you can use the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) which has extra functionality to:

1. handle transparent components
2. create an image of an area of the component
3. create an image of a component not displayed on a visible window
4. write to image to a file